# Eclipse IDE white outlines in the project explorer

Tags: eclipse

I keep having these white outlines in the project explorer, how do i turn them off and what are they?

[image: Example]

Comment: I think Eclipse marks in this way changed files according to git status.

Comment: This wouldn't be the case if you were using the current version of Eclipse with one of its standard themes. If an upgrade doesn't help, contact the support of Genuitec as one of their closed-source plug-ins is causing this.